# Null Pointer on onClick()

Tags: java, android, onclick, nullpointerexception

I have an android app that some users are reporting a null pointer on the onClick method of the code below. Log shows line 226 and thats where selectedAlbum.getId() is check for null. I don't experience the error but market reports show this error on 2 devices. What can I do to fix this?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v("uploadButton", "uploadButton Clicked");

                if ((selectedAlbum.getId() == null)
                        || (selectedAlbum.getId() == "")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please Select an Album First", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();

                } else {

                    if (m_photos.isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "No Pictures Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    } else {

                        // Do action to upload photos from array to facebook
                        progressDialog = ProgressDialog
                                .show(EasyPhotoUpload.this, "",
                                        "Uploading Photos...");
                        Log.v("uploadButton", "Starting upload thread");
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Log.v("uploadButton", "running.....");
```

here is the code where selectedAlbum is set.

```
public class AlbumSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
                long id) {
            selectedAlbum = (Album) albumSpinner.getItemAtPosition(pos);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {/* not implemented */
        }
    }
```

selectedAlbum is also set before the activity begins and onCreate.

```
public Album selectedAlbum;
```

Comment: May be selectedAlbum is null, and you call selectedAlbum.getId().it's will throw null pointer exception.

Comment: Please post the code that assigns a value to selectedAlbum.

Comment: I see you updated the question with where `selectAlbum` is initialized. How does the onClick() method factor in? Is this a button that is always visible, is it hidden until an album is selected, or something else?

Comment: @Sam It is always visible, they click the button and selectedAlbum is connect to a spinner element. If the spinner is empty then the user is notified to select something.

Comment: But you cannot recreate the error yourself by simply pushing the Button before selecting an album in your Spinner?

Comment: I still don't think the error is in the posted code. Most likely selectedAlbum is not being initialized (or is being set to null after being initialized). You need to look at EVERY line of code that sets the value of selectedAlbum and decide if that line could possibly a) assign a null value OR b) be skipped for some reason. Your error is coming from the market because users always find a way to execute your code in ways you didn't expect.

Comment: In onItemSelected() you assume that parent == albumSpinner. Strictly speaking, you should be calling **parent**.getItemAtPosition(). If your AlbumSelectedListener is listening to more than one spinner then it may accidentally assign a null to selectedAlbum.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've provided the wrong code snippet.  If the NPE is at

```
if ((selectedAlbum.getId() == null)
```

...then `selectedAlbum` is null and you can't call `null.getId()`

Comment: True, by why would this happen on some phones and not others? How can I prevent?

Comment: if( selectedAlbum == null || selectedAlbum.getId() == null )

Answer (score 0):

To stop the app from crashing simply check `if(selectedAlbum == null)`. If it is, handle the situation gracefully and save the user from experiencing a force close.

Perhaps present a Toast or Dialog asking the user to "Please select an album". Without seeing how `selectAlbum` is assigned a value it is impossible to know why only two phones created this error report. These users may have clicked a series of buttons that you hadn't predicted or it may be a manufacturer's quirk... It's impossible to know without more information.

Comment: While this is technically a solution to keep the app from crashing, you might also want to investigate whether it logically makes sense for this ever to be null (presumably when the user hasn't yet selected an album..)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that with few having the error the app failed to retrieve the album list from Facebook due to a error on the users end. The this has now been resolved. Thanks to those who responded.